# Accessing SharePoint Web Service from Android

Tags: android, web-services, sharepoint, ksoap2

I am trying to access share point web service from my android app.

I used KSoap to access web service but every time it is throwing error at below line.

"androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);"

So I tried with following link but it is returning "Fault String".

http://www.robertkuzma.com/2011/07/manipulating-sharepoint-list-items-with-android-java-and-ntlm-authentication/

Please help me whether problem is from app side or Server Side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you use Ksoap webservice to get data?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
public static String call(Context c, SoapObject request, String NAMESPACE,
            String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION) throws IOException,
            XmlPullParserException {
        Log.i(WebCalls, "URL " + CommonVariable.URL);
        Log.i(WebCalls, "Method Name " + METHOD_NAME);
        Log.i(WebCalls, "request Name " + request);
        String SoapResult = null;
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        envelope.dotNet = true;

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                CommonVariable.URL);

        // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
        if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
            SoapResult = ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
        } else {
            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            SoapResult = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString();
        }

        Log.i(WebCalls, "Response " + SoapResult);

        return SoapResult;
    }
```

Comment: Hi dipali thanks for your reply and I am using same code but I am getting exception here:"androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);" Exception is :"org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40d16600)"

Comment: @hcp have you pass right namespace ,url ,soap action?

Comment: private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/" ;
private static final String URL = "http://MyWCFApp/Service.svc";

Comment: Yes I passed Correct only.My NAMESPACE is : "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" and SOAP ACTION will be like:NAMESPACE/METHODNAME

Comment: OK thanks I will change that and Update the status as soon as possible.

Comment: @dipali I am not want to Authenticate using azure so have any idea about it..??  i found one blog it work but after connectivity i  was call REST web service to get list items and get json respons. but i faced one problem that give me just 100 jsonArray data where in that list there is 1000 items. so please can you help me in that.

Comment: @VishalHalani plz put your question in Stackoverflow site.and just give me link..so i understand ur problem.

Comment: @dipali I cant post any question now because its block for me now so yr.

Comment: @dipali i just want listitems from sharepoint. using soap please have any example or code so i can understand flow of code.

Comment: @VishalHalani my above code is working fine in my app.plz try it

Comment: @dipali in your code where you define list name which items i want to get?